# Android app for organizing/tracking of custom collectible cards

Tags: android, collection-manager

I am looking for an Android application to track/organize custom [collectible cards/trading cards](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trading_card_game). I am searching for some time, but either such app doesn't exist or my Google-fu is weak. Do you have any tip for such application?

What I basically want to do is to take a photo of front and back side of the card, put a name to it and then just be able to search/swipe through the collection.

I am not interested in app related to [*MTG*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic:_The_Gathering) etc. as they cover specific game and already existing cards.

Comment: Would you be able to adapt some kind of home inventory app?

Comment: I have briefly checked some, but they are in most cases heavily oriented for inventory and contains too many unnecessary features for my purpose.

Comment: Probably a useless comment but I know [Gordie](http://gordie-app.bitbucket.org/) which maybe could do the job better than nothing. It's a Windows/Linux software and doesn't seem to support adding pictures of cards, but thought I'd share it in the comments anyway.